# Почему выкидывается исключения при работе с указателем

Tags: c++

Объясните почему Visual Studio кидает Exception thrown: write access violation.

```
 char const* const_str = "Alex";
 char* non_const_str=const_cast<char*>(const_str);
 *non_const_str= 'y';
```

хотя oператор приведения const_cast по идее удаляет модификатор const.

Comment: Нет, он ничего не удаляет, он только позволяет получить указатель, содержащий тот же адрес, но без const квалификатора. Что можно было бы сделать посредством `memcpy`.

Comment: В Си константность это атрибут для удобства. А ошибка доступа к памяти это совсем другое. Вы пытаетесь модифицировать выполняющийся код.

Answer (score 3):

В данном случаи сбрасывание `const` вам ничего не даст, потому что  "Alex" является литералом, а следовательно константным выражением, известным во время компиляции, и вы не можете во время выполнения изменять эту строку(любое константное выражение).  А вот если тот же константный указатель `const_str` указывал бы на массив(или другой объект), то вы могли бы сбросить const квалификатор,  получив не константный указатель, чтобы записать в строку:

```
char a[] = "Alex"; 
char const* const_str = a;
char* non_const_str = const_cast<char*>(const_str);
non_const_str[0] = 'y';
cout << *non_const_str;
```

Comment: Если ближе к делу, то просто константы размещают в защищенной от записи памяти (реализуется атрибутами доступа в карте виртуальной памяти)

Comment: @avp, да,  это уместное дополнение.

Comment: Если ещё точнее говорить, то константы могут размещается в памяти, которая защищена от записи и компилятор имеет полное право считать, что эти данные не могут изменится.